# Select all data with same ID in a table

Tags: sql

I just want to know the correct syntax because what I've done is not what I wanted. So here is the sample table on database,

```
|ID    |BOOKS   |COURSE
+------+--------+------+
|1     |web book| A    |
|1     |java    | A    |
|2     |php     | B    |
|2     |html    | B    |
```

In my UI, I have this table. I have a button in the column of the table that will trigger a modal to show the  borrowed books of the student in that row.

```
|ID    |COURSE|ACTION|
+------+------+------+
|1     |A     |SHOW  |
|2     |B     |SHOW  |
```

Whenever I want to show the borrowed book of ID = 1, the output on modals should be like

```
|BOOKS   |
+--------+
|web book|
|java    |
```

because that's what ID=1 borrowed. Thanks in advance.

My current query:

```
SELECT book
FROM borrowing_tbl
where ID in (SELECT ID
             FROM borrowing_tbl
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

it keeps showing all data with duplicated ID

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I don't follow your data.  How do courses of `A` and `B` translate to the web and Java books?

Comment: @jarlh SELECT book FROM borrowing_tbl where ID in (SELECT ID FROM borrowing_tbl GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

it keeps showing all data with duplicated ID

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry i forgot to inlcude the COURSE column in database part

Answer (score 0):

Select all books with ID 1

```
Select ID
 From BOOKS
 Where BOOKS.ID = 1
```

I'm sure you could lay your tables out better

Edit:

```
SELECT BOOKS.name
FROM BOOKS
JOIN students on students.id = BOOKS.id
WHERE students.courses = 'A';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want the output to show the distinct ID with different books.

Comment: The id column is probably integer, so use a simple integer literal instead of a character string literal. I.e. `Where BOOKS.ID = 1`.

Comment: I didn't even see that, too early in the morning, check my edit